# node, How to handle/catch pipe

Tags: node.js, node.js-stream

I've seen and read a few tutorials that state you can pipe one stream to another almost like lego blocks, but I can't find anything on how to catch a pipe command when a stream is piped to your object.

What I mean is how do I create an object with functions so I can do:

```
uploadWrapper = function (client, file, callback) {
  upload = function (client,file,callback){
    var file = file
    // this.data = 'undefined'
    stream.Writable.call(this);
    this.end = function () {
        if(typeof this.data !== 'undefined') file.data = this.data
        callback(file.data,200)
    }
    // var path = urlB.host('upload').object('files',file.id).action('content').url
    // // client.upload(path,file,callback)
  }
  util.inherits(upload,stream.Writable)

  upload.prototype._write = function (chunk, encoding, callback) {
    this.data = this.data + chunk.toString('utf8')
    callback()
  }

      return new upload(client,file,callback)
}
exports.upload = uploadWrapper
```

How do I handle when data is piped to my object?

I've looked but I can't really find anything about this (maybe I haven't looked in the write places?).

Can any one point me in the right direction?

If it helps to know it, all I Want to be able to do is catch a data stream and build a string containing data with binary encoding; whether it's from a file-stream or a request stream from a server(i.e. the data from a file of a multipart request) object.

EDIT: I've updated the code to log the data

EDIT: I've fixed it, I can now receive piped data, I had to put the code in a wrapper that returned the function that implemented stream.

EDIT: different problem now, `this.data` in `_read` isn't storing in a way that `this.data` in the upload function can read.

EDIT: OK, now I can deal with the callback and catch the data, I need to work out how to tell if data is being piped to it or if it's being used as a normal function.

Comment: It sounds like you're making this more complex than it need be.  If you just want to handle incoming data from your file stream, just add an `.on('data', cb);` event handler.  If you truly need to pipe it to your object, make sure your object is a writable stream.

Comment: Do you mean something like that?(see changed example)

Comment: What is `client`? Is it possible to stream the upload instead of buffering all data written to your stream?

Comment: Client is a module I've built, it's apart of an SDK for box that I've been working on. File uploads work, but at the moment the data has to be supplied either directly (from the file on the server) or from a string containing the data encoded in binary. At least with this (piping) it would allow me to catch data from an incoming stream, say from a multi-part form or a file-stream or any stream really.

Comment: I still think the best way to handle this is to add an `on data` handler, and not mess with `pipe`, and I may be able to write up such an example a little later.  Aside from that, you've started down the correct path for making your object a writable stream, so keep following that if that's the route you want to take, and I'll see what I can add on this option as well.

Comment: How would I do the 'on data' handler? Can I just pass the stream object though to my function? I won't lie, part of the reason I Want to be able to use pipe is just for the sake of learning it, but also because I think being able to just .pipe is really elegant. p.s. How do I differentiate between file streams and form streams so I can format accordingly?

Comment: streams are streams, the only difference is whether they are writable or readable.

Comment: So it would be the content I would need to differentiate between? I guess I'd need to parse the form data, then.

Comment: It occurs to me that I'm not really sure what it is you're trying to accomplish.  I started to write up an example but found that it may not apply depending on your circumstances.  Can you lay out the broad strokes of what you're trying to accomplish in terms of what sort of data you're receiving, and what you're trying to do with it?

Comment: I'm trying to copy the request module in that you can either pipe a multiform stream to it, a file stream or make a request directly. I'm trying to make a function that a person can use to upload a file with; either, with just the file path(file local to the server), the file data in binary encoding OR pipe a file-stream to it OR pipe a multiform stream.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to create your own stream that can be piped to and/or from, look at the node [docs for implementing streams](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/stream.html#stream_api_for_stream_implementors).

Comment: I will have a proper look at this tomorrow, but I think this might be exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Would that work?(See updated code example) What I want to catch is data from a file and put it with binary encoding whether it's from a request stream from a multipart post request or from a file stream so how do I differentiate (from file and form stream) and catch it?